# Aggregate by Day produces duplicate day results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

My mongodb aggregation query should return daily, weekly, monthly, yearly data within specific date ranges.

Example: let's assume dates between 1st Feb to 1st March.

the data for daily should be: 1st, 2nd, 3rd.. 
Weekly period will be: 1st Feb, 8th Feb, 15th Feb, 22nd Feb ..
monthly period will be 1st Feb, 1st march ..

Look at example below:

Let's say my API accepts: startDate, endDate, interval as body params.

req.body will be something like this:

```
{
startDate: "",
endDate: "",
platform: "",
interval: "daily" // could be "weekly", "monthly", "yearly"
}
```

These params will be passed to my model where I have some aggregation code which will be mentioned below:

```
MessagesSchema.statics.totalMessages = ( startDate, endDate, platform, interval ) => {
        return Messages.aggregate([{
                $match: {
                    platform: platform,
                    timestamp: {
                        $gte: new Date(startDate),
                        $lte: new Date(endDate)
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    timestamp: {
                        $dateToString: {
                            format: '%Y-%m-%d',
                            date: '$timestamp'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: {
                        timestamp: '$timestamp'
                    },
                    count: {
                        $sum: 1
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $sort: {
                    '_id.timestamp': 1
                }
            }
        ]).exec();
```

Let's assume Weekly data from 1st Feb 2019 - 1st March 2019;

expected result:

```
[
    {
      "_id": {
        "timestamp": "2019-02-01"
      },
      "count": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "timestamp": "2019-02-08"
      },
      "count": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "timestamp": "2019-02-15"
      },
      "count": 2
    }
]
```

actual result:

```
[
    {
      "_id": {
        "timestamp": "2019-02-01"
      },
      "count": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "timestamp": "2019-03-02"
      },
      "count": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "timestamp": "2019-03-02"
      },
      "count": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: You'r claiming that an `_id` ( primary key ) of `$group` produces the same value twice. Please show documents to reproduce your claim from. But also check your results because that actually cannot happen. Or at least not as a result from the code specified in the question. BTW, Editng your title to reflect what you are actually asking.

Comment: Dude, You totally got my question wrong! How do I change the question ??? Please undo the changes if you can.

Comment: I guess you can help me with this. Let me explain you. But first, Please undo the changes. As you totally got me wrong